# Unable to update UI elements when using TPL through nested methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, progress-bar, task-parallel-library

I am trying to update UI elements from multiple methods using TPL. The elements get updated when the first method is executed but when the child methods nested in the first method are called, I get an `InvalidOperationException`-The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler. I even tried to convert the code to the `async` - `await` pattern but did not succeed.

EDIT 1: Not able to reproduce the InvalidOperationException. I am getting this error now - The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.

EDIT 2: Reproduced the InvalidOperationException. It was caused due to The curren SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler. Stack Trace as below:

> at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler..ctor()
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
>   at IntegratedTracker.IntegratedTracker.ProgressReporter..ctor() in
>   at IntegratedTracker.IntegratedTracker.UploadToDb() in
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Also, I noticed that if I call the UpdateValuesInDb method in a button_click event, the updates flow through to the UI.

My code is submitted below along with the research I've done which is in comments within the code.

```
private void btnUploadToDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UploadToDb();
}

private static void UploadToDb()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxRecords - 1; i++)
        {
            // Code for inserting into Db.

            // Update progress to progressbar and label on UI form.
            // Borrowed from Stephen Cleary's article
            // http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html
            progressReporter.ReportProgress(() => { 
                // Can this be done in a better way than enclosing in a 
                // ReportProgress before entering the for loop?                     
                progressbar.maximum=maxRecords; 
                label.text="Uploading " + i;
                progressbar.value=i;
            });
        }

        progressReporter.ReportProgress(() => {
            label.Text = "Updating values in DB, please wait...";
        });

        // When this call is made the subsequent updates to the main form 
        // were not successful due to 'InvalidOperationException'.
        UpdateValuesInDb();     
    });
}

private void UpdateValuesInDb();
{
    // Code for updating the values.

    // The below method should be called in sequence and labels updated in the same sequence.

    // Report progress to UI for values of type 1.
    // label.text="Moving values of type 1..."; // This has not been implemented because of cross thread exceptions
                            // This is what I'd like to achieve.
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(values); // This call has to complete first

    // Report progress to UI for values of type 2.
    // label.text="Moving values of type 2..."; // This has not been implemented because of cross thread exceptions
                            // This is what I'd like to achieve.
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(values); // This call has to complete second.

    // Report progress to UI for values of type 3.
    label.text="Moving values of type 3...";    // This has not been implemented because of cross thread exceptions
                            // This is what I'd like to achieve.
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(values); // This call has to complete third.

    // Report progress to UI for values of type 4.
    // label.text="Moving values of type 4..."; // This has not been implemented because of cross thread exceptions
                            // This is what I'd like to achieve.
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(values); // This call is the final.
}


private void MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(string values)
{
    var progressReporter = new ProgressReporter();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // Tried using Stephen Cleary's code here but it fails with 
                    progressReporter.ReportProgress(() =>
                    {
                        progressBar.Maximum = maxRecords - 1;
                        Label.Text = "Uploading " + i;
                        progressBar.Value = i;
                    });
            // Need to update label and progress in for loop as mentioned above.
        }
    });
}
```

I even tried to convert the existing code to use the async-await method but it failed during compile stating that it is not awaitable.
This is what I tried changing:

```
private async void btnUploadToDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await UploadToDb(); // Got the error Type System.Threading.Tasks.Task is not awaitable.
}

private async Task UploadToDb()
{
    // Codes is same as the previous one, I've just used the async 
    // modifier, though I do not know what to await here.

    // Tried to assign await as follows:
    await   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // Need to update label and progress bar here.
        }
    });

    // The above results in a compile error:
    // 'Type System.Threading.Tasks.Task is not awaitable'.
}
```

I've even searched tutorials on TPL, TPL for beginners etc, but none of this was helpful to address my issue.

In addition, I'd like to know if we need to dispose tasks that are created or if these are disposed automatically like the using blocks. If an exception is encountered before the task completes do we need to dispose the task?

I am quite new to TPL and I am struggling with the concepts, hence I would really appreciate some help.

Forgot to mention, I am using VS2010, .Net 4.0 and this is for a Windows Forms application.

Comment: Can you provide the StackTrace of InvalidOperationException?

Comment: @vendettamit, sorry, I am not able to reproduce that issue now, I've been trying my luck at changing the code to make it work, so there have been lots of edits. I've edited the post to reflect what I am getting right now. hope that helps. It is still not updating the UI when nested methods are called.

Comment: @vendettamit, I was able to reproduce the issue now. The InvalidOperationException was caused due to The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler. I've added the stack trace under EDIT 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is running in STAThreadApartment then it might happen.

Try using ConfigureAwait(false) calling on your task to prevent the default SyncThreadContext to be used.

Though It might change the behaviour of Async. But this might solve the problem if My assumption are correct.

> Update: You're on .Net 4.0 so ConfigureAwait is out of context.

The problem could be that your Synchrnoization context may be setting back to null when you're creating Task from nested methods. You can fetch the current Synchronization context from parent method and use the same context for all nested methods.

I have updated your code:

```
 private static void UploadToDb()
 {
     var currentSyncContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

     Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
     {
         for (int i = 0; i <= maxRecords - 1; i++)
         {
             progressReporter.ReportProgress(() => { 

                 progressbar.maximum=maxRecords; 
                 label.text="Uploading " + i;
                 progressbar.value=i;
             });
         }

                progressReporter.ReportProgress(() => {
             label.Text = "Updating values in DB, please wait...";
         });

     // When this call is made the subsequent updates to the main form 
     // were not successful due to 'InvalidOperationException'.
     UpdateValuesInDb(currentSyncContext); 

     });
}

private void UpdateValuesInDb(SynchronizationContext context);
{

    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(values, context); 
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(values, context); 
    label.text="Moving values of type 3...";    
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(values, context); 
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(values, context); // This call is the final.
}


private void MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(string values, SynchronizationContext context)
{
    var progressReporter = new ProgressReporter();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // Tried using Stephen Cleary's code here but it fails with 
                    progressReporter.ReportProgress(() =>
                    {
                        progressBar.Maximum = maxRecords - 1;
                        Label.Text = "Uploading " + i;
                        progressBar.Value = i;
                    });
            // Need to update label and progress in for loop as mentioned above.
        }
    }, context);
}
```

Comment: where in the code should I use the above. I'm sorry I didn't understand.

Comment: Your idea of passing the current synchronization context combined with the solution what Stephen Cleary gave in the answer below is what helped me solve the issue. I will be posting the code that solved this shortly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`ProgressReporter` must be created on the UI thread. So, you need to move the line `var progressReporter = new ProgressReporter();` from the top of `MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb` to the top of `UploadToDb`.

And **strongly** consider upgrading your Visual Studio version. This is far, far easier with `async`/`await` and `IProgress<T>` instead of `ProgressReporter`.

Comment: taking your advice and moving the progressReporter to the main thread and passing the same as a parameter in the nested methods as advised by vendettamit in the above answer, helped me solve this problem. I am not using .Net 4.5 to be able to use IProgress or async/await because the client is using .Net 4.0. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @svb: `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` brings `IProgress<T>` and `async`/`await` support to .NET 4.0. You're stuck using old technologies because your VS is 5 years (almost 3 major versions) out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to start a new task in your `MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb` method, because:

> The below method should be called in sequence and labels updated in the same sequence.

Why not change that method to something like this:

```
private void MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb(string valuesType, string values)
{
    progressReporter.ReportProgress(() => {
        label.text = string.Format("Moving values of type {0}...", valuesType);
    });

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        // Do your move values thing.

        // Report progress
        progressReporter.ReportProgress(() => {
           // ...
        });
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
private void UpdateValuesInDb();
{
    // Code for updating the values.

    // The below method should be called in sequence 
    // and labels updated in the same sequence.
    // for type "1" .. "4".
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb("1", values); 
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb("2", values); 
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb("3", values); 
    MoveValuesToNewDbDeleteFromSourceDb("4", values); 
}
```

Note: as mentioned in the blog, the `ProgressReporter` is "deprecated":

> Update, 2012-02-16: The information in this post is old. See the new post [Reporting Progress from Async Tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html) for a better solution.

Second note: I am assuming that your `progressReporter` instance is a member variable, that is created **on your UI thread**. If that is not the case, this explains why you are having trouble: **make it a member variable, construct it when your form is created.**

Finally, you could use a far simpler implementation for your needs.

```
public class ProgressReporter
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public void ReportProgress(Action progressAction)
    {
        _syncContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(unused => progressAction()), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've given the above a shot, but it still throws the same error i.e. The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.

Comment: Interestingly, when I call the UpdateValuesInDb() by using a button_click event, it causes the UI to hang but once the operation is complete, the expected label value is displayed on UI. Though ideally it should have been displaying real-time increments than just the static number.

Comment: I can't use Iprogess<T> as it is .Net 4.5 and I am using  4.0,

Comment: @svb are you creating the `progressReporter` instance when your form is being created, as one of its member variables?

Comment: No, I've created a class and Im calling it from there. It works fine when there are no nested methods. It fails when one method calls another.